# Traversing Relationships a Variable Number of Times in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-theory, graph-traversal

I have a graph of Airports, Routes between them and Airlines that carry it. I created routes as separate nodes, rather than just a relationship, so that I can connect each with an Airline, and other nodes.

Each `Route` node has an `IS_FROM` relationship with the origin airport and an `IS_TO` relationship with the destination. It also has an `IS_BY` relationship with its airline:
[image]

I am trying to traverse this tree, `n` times, for routes between two airports. For example, if `n = 3`, I want to get all the routes, that will lead from `LAX` to `LHR`, with 3 or fewer connections.

So basically, my result would be a union of the following:
No Connecting Airports:

```
MATCH (a1:Airport {iata : 'LAX'})<-[:IS_FROM]-(r:Route)-[:IS_TO]->(a2:Airport {iata : 'LHR'}), (r)-[:IS_BY]->(ai:Airline) return a1 , r , a2 , ai;
```

1 Connecting airports:

```
MATCH (a1:Airport {iata : 'LAX'})<-[:IS_FROM]-(r:Route)-[:IS_TO]->(a2:Airport)<-[IS_FROM]-(r2:Route)-[:IS_TO]->(a3:Airport {iata: 'LHR'}), (r2)-[:IS_BY]->(ai:Airline) return a1 , r , a2 , a3 , r2 , ai;
```

and so on.

So the query should dynamically traverse the `(:Airport)<-[:IS_FROM]-(:Route)-[:IS_TO]->(:Airport)` pattern n times, and return the nodes (I am more interested in returning the  `Airline`s that connect to those routes.

Comment: Do you want the result in the Neo4j Browser or do you want to consume it as a json or something?

Comment: I'm trying to write the query in Neo4J, but ultimately I have an application connected that'll use the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first extract all the paths between Airports that are 3 or less hops away, and then use `OPTIONAL MATCH` to see which of the nodes in the path are Routes, and which Airlines are offering them.

```
MATCH path = (:Airport {iata:$start_airport})-[*2..6]-(:Airport {iata:$end_airport})
WITH path,nodes(path) as path_airports_and_connecting_routes
UNWIND path_airports_and_connecting_routes as node
OPTIONAL MATCH (node)-[:IS_BY]-(airline:Airline)
WITH collect(node) as airports_and_routes,airline
RETURN airports_and_routes + [airline]
```

Caveat: Variable-length paths don't allow passing parameters, so you can't do something like `[*2..2*n]`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i got your question right. To me your problem could be solved this way:

```
MATCH (a1:Airport {iata : 'LAX'})<-[r1:IS_FROM]-(r:Route)-[r2:IS_TO]->(a2:Airport{iata : 'LHR'})
OPTIONAL MATCH (r)-[r3:IS_BY]->(ai:Airline)
RETURN a1,r1,r,r2,a2,r3,ai
```

Comment: Thanks for that. No. What I'm trying to accomplish is finding "indirect" routes between two airports. I want to be able to specify the number of airports I'll be okay to have in between and get all the routes accordingly.